# How to change the font style in Radio Button?

Tags: html, css, fonts

```css
.rad > input {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
.rad > i {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 8px #fff;
  border: 0.5px solid gray;
}
.rad > input:checked + i {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #fff;
  background: #ffc000;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label class="rad">
    <input type="radio" name="r1" value="a" checked="checked" />
    <i></i> Male
  </label>
  <label class="rad">
    <input type="radio" name="r1" value="b" />
    <i></i> Female
  </label>
</p>
```

I have to change the font style with:

```
font-family:SegoeUI-SemiBold;
font-size:12px;color:#535353;text-align:left;
```

these are the things should be added.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Font size,color,style is not changing.

Comment: I have added a screenshot in my answer. Tell me if the colour there is right? Because `#535353` is the colour which I see.

Comment: Can you kindly check again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just add the same styles to your `<p>` tag:

```css
p {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI SemiBold';
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #535353;
  text-align: left;
}
.rad > input {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
.rad > i {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 8px #fff;
  border: 0.5px solid gray;
}
.rad > input:checked + i {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #fff;
  background: #ffc000;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label class="rad">
    <input type="radio" name="r1" value="a" checked="checked" />
    <i></i> Male
  </label>
  <label class="rad">
    <input type="radio" name="r1" value="b" />
    <i></i> Female
  </label>
</p>
```

Works fine for me, when you use the font correctly as `font-family: 'Segoe UI SemiBold';`:

[image]

Better Screenshot:

[image]

**Update**

The selected Radio should have a different colour. You need to use a `<span>` for this case:

```css
p {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI SemiBold';
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #535353;
  text-align: left;
}
.rad > input {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
.rad > i {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 8px #fff;
  border: 0.5px solid gray;
}
.rad > input:checked + i {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #fff;
  background: #ffc000;
}
.rad > input:checked ~ span {
  color: #979797;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label class="rad">
    <input type="radio" name="r1" value="a" checked="checked" />
    <i></i> <span>Male</span>
  </label>
  <label class="rad">
    <input type="radio" name="r1" value="b" />
    <i></i> <span>Female</span>
  </label>
</p>
```

Comment: If i click the Female button the color of the font should be "color:#979797;"

Comment: @Sriram You didn't say that. You need to change the HTML. Is that okay?

Comment: font as well as the the radio button

Comment: @Sriram Updated. Refresh and see the new snippet in the bottom. Happy to help you.

Comment: @Sriram Let me know if you have any more questions. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111207/discussion-between-sriram-and-praveen-kumar).